# Blinking the taskbar icon when a SQL query completes

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-7, windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

On my work PC I run all my SQL Server 2008 queries on a remote desktop connection to Microsoft Server 2008. Because of this I often have the window minimized and check it occasionally to see if a query has run.

Does anyone know if I can write any kind of script to blink the Windows 7 taskbar icon when a query completes. A pop up warning box would also work, anything to grab my attention whilst I'm surfing the web waiting for a query to complete.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: whilst waiting, surf the web for a solution? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set SSMS to play a sound to notify you, there's a [link here](http://benchmarkitconsulting.com/colin-stasiuk/2009/03/26/sound-notification-when-query-finishes-executing/) that shows you how to set this up in options.